# Once I tame a mantis what do i need to feed it?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

So I am planning on taming a mantis on scorched earth. I already know that it is a passive tame and requires deathworm horns (or is it called thorns). Now lets say i tame a mantis. What sort of food does it need to eat after it is tamed? The wiki was rather unclear and I am trying to determine whether the mantis is worth it or not.

Comment: The wiki says it's diet is carnivorous. Can you feed it meats?

Comment: I don't know yet. That's what I want to know so I can decide if they are worth the resources, time and engram points.

Comment: The only [info I could find](https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/87189-i-would-like-to-tame-a-mantis/) says it only consumes deathworm horns.  Whether or not this is accurate though I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a [quick Google search](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Mantis), it states that:

> The Mantis is unable to be tamed through the standard tranquilize-and-feed methods, and must be tamed non-violently.
>
> To feed it, place a Deathworm Horn in the last slot of your hotbar, then when approached press "use" (default E) to feed it. You cannot feed them all the horns required for taming at one time, you must wait a few minutes after each feeding to give it the next one, and repeat until the taming meter is filled.
>
> The Mantis is normally aggressive, so Bug Repellent is needed in order to get close enough to feed it. A set of Ghillie Armor is also useful, but not required. The Mantis becomes aggressive if you are too close. The taming progress will become halted until it loses interest in whatever it was fighting, or even decrease if it's aggressive for too long.
>
> A good trap to tame the mantis is a single foundation (Stone, Adobe, or Metal) with 4 walls on the first level, and 3 walls on the second level.[1](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Mantis) Lastly add two ramps to the last opening on the second level. Part of the mantis will stick outside of the trap and you can feed it. You will not need any Bug Repellent or Ghillie Armor with this method.

And that it's a carnivore, so meats are the diet

Answer (score 1):

Manti, like the Pulminoscorpius, eats rotten meat once it is tamed.